# Embedded SVG misaligned to element

Tags: html, css, asp.net, svg

So I'm trying to move from PNG to SVG, but I'm having some growing pains. I'd like to use embedded SVG so I can change their CSS attributes for their colour as well as having fewer resource loads. Although an issue I'm having is when the SVG is embedded it appears above the box provided, although if I use an img tag with linking to the SVG, the formatting is perfect.

In my picture, the box on the right has the img tag while the left box is embedded.

http://jsfiddle.net/fLWhu/684/

```
<span>
                            @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/icons/1.svg")))

</span>
<span>
<img src="~/Content/images/icons/1.svg" alt="our linked in" /> 
</span>
```

[image]

Update:

After adding the

```
     display:inline-block;
     vertical-align:middle;
```

into the span, the result is.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG part seems ok, you could try set a display:inline-block and vertical align:middle to the **div.header .right p span** element

Comment: Thank you, that did bring down the SVG, although it's still not aligned perfectly and is aligned a little higher. I'm looking through all the CSS trying to figure why.

It's pretty consistent, I think I'll hide the issue with some padding.